# Angular - Spring boot - Http failure response for ... 400 OK, error: null

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have problems when I do a POST request in Angular and Java/Spring Boot.

This is my request:

```
sendTask(dismissDTO: DismissDTO): Observable<RemoteTaskDTO> {
    const URL: string = '/manager/employees/send-dismiss';
    return this.httpClient.post<RemoteTaskDTO>(URL, dismissDTO);
  }
```

And this is my endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeService employeeServiceImpl;

  ...

  @PostMapping("send-dismiss")
  public ResponseEntity<RemoteTaskDTO> sendDismissHHRR(@RequestBody DismissDTO dismissDTO) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeServiceImpl.sendTaskDismiss(dismissDTO));
  }
}
```

These are the DTO models:

```
@Data
public class DismissDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ProcessInDTO inDTO;
    private ConversationDTO conversation;
    private String idOldTask;
    private String idNewTask;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProcessInDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8119148383341404412L;

    private String processKey;
    private String executionId;
    private String assigmentId;
    private String taskId;
    private Integer pageNumber;
    private Integer pageSize;
    private String role;
    private Integer priority;
    private String idProcessInstance;
    private Map<String, Object> parameters;
    List<TaskParameterUrlDTO> parametersUrl = new ArrayList<TaskParameterUrlDTO>();
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "messages" })
@ToString(exclude = { "messages" })
public class ConversationDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private Long idAssociated;
    private TaskTypeDTO taskType;
    private FlowDTO flow;
    private RoleDTO role;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("conversation")
    private List<MessageDTO> messages= new ArrayList<MessageDTO>();
}
```

The problem is, when I do a deployment and test the request, it fails and shows the error:

```
error: null
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()}
message: "HTTP failure response for http://localhost:4200/manager/employees/send-dismiss: 400 OK"
name: "httpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:4200/manager/employees/send-dismiss"
```

The weird thing is that when I redeploy the Spring Boot application, it works. I don't know what could be the problem.

Any help is good. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try with postman instead your angular app?

Comment: I just did it. It also fails. The same result:
Status: 400 Bad Request   Time: 513 ms   Size: 340 B

Comment: Could you try with curl -v and share the success and error result in the question. Also the logs of both tests would be helpful

Comment: can u show ur both DTOs ?

Comment: I have added the DTOs.

Comment: Are you using jackson dependency? or maybe you need to add the consumes to your webserivce -> consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Comment: 400 means bad request, or in another words, your client (angular/postman) is sending a wrong request, maybe a missing field, incorrect datatype, etc. Just to try, remove all fields in DismissDTO and keep just one simple string and perform a invocation with your postman or curl.

Comment: I thought that was the error, but the request is the same, same values. Some times it is success, other times no. I will try adding the media type.

Comment: I tried with the media type consumes and it didn't work. And it is weird, because when I added the name and the media type params, the request failed each time, even after I restarted the spring boot app.